# Generating a GeoJSON MultiLineString Feature with multiple lines from a GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I'm trying to create some GeoJSON directly from PostGIS (v3.1; Postgres 13.2) and have gotten surprisingly far, considering my aversion to raw SQL queries.

Specifically, I want to create a `Feature` with a `MultiLineString`. Here's some code:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'bbox',       ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_MakeLine(lines.line), 6, 1)::jsonb-> 'bbox',
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Multi(ST_MakeLine(lines.line)), 6)::jsonb,
    'properties', jsonb_build_object(
        'lineProperties',        jsonb_build_object(
            'ids',   array_agg(lines.track_id)
        ),
        'coordinateProperties',  jsonb_build_object(
            'times',   array_agg(lines.time)
        )
    )
)
FROM (
    SELECT track_id, array_agg(extract(epoch from logged_at)) as time, ST_Collect(point::geometry ORDER BY created_at) as line
    FROM coordinates
    WHERE locatable_id = :id
    and user_id = :user_id
    GROUP BY track_id
) lines;
```

This gives me a result like this:

```json
{
    "bbox": [-165.771653, -82.394628, 150.356346, 85.163403], 
    "type": "Feature", 
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString", 
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [-93.644346, 32.831718], 
                [-132.701578, -79.916542], 
                [74.115335, -20.866482], 
                [-79.272251, -27.737648], 
                [73.539323, 12.806696], 
                [54.706111, -51.355516], 
                [-165.771653, -74.537204], 
                [150.356346, 85.163403], 
                [81.45228, -82.394628], 
                [-151.595094, 62.69771]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "lineProperties": {
            "ids": [
                "93238588-8beb-4174-ac1c-6cd2ac179bdc", 
                "93238588-8c67-4dc2-87af-991d5263c02e"
            ]
        }, 
        "coordinateProperties": {
            "times": [
                [null, null, null, null, null], 
                [null, null, null, null, null]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What I am really after, tho is the following:

```json
{
    "bbox": [-165.771653, -82.394628, 150.356346, 85.163403], 
    "type": "Feature", 
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString", 
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [-93.644346, 32.831718], 
                [-132.701578, -79.916542], 
                [74.115335, -20.866482], 
                [-79.272251, -27.737648], 
                [73.539323, 12.806696]
            ],
            [
                [54.706111, -51.355516], 
                [-165.771653, -74.537204], 
                [150.356346, 85.163403], 
                [81.45228, -82.394628], 
                [-151.595094, 62.69771]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "lineProperties": {
            "ids": [
                "93238588-8beb-4174-ac1c-6cd2ac179bdc", 
                "93238588-8c67-4dc2-87af-991d5263c02e"
            ]
        }, 
        "coordinateProperties": {
            "times": [
                [null, null, null, null, null], 
                [null, null, null, null, null]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want a `MultiLineString` with multiple line strings based on their `track_id`, much like `coordinateProperties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST_MakeLine` uses an aggregation of *all* *POINT* components of *all* *MultiPoint* geometries (created via `ST_Collect`) in the result set of the sub-query to create a single *Linestring*.

Rather, you want to `ST_MakeLine` a *Linestring* **for each `track_id`** and then `ST_Collect` them into a *MultiLinestring*; I'd also move much of the GeoJSON structure definition into the sub-query like so

```
SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(line.geom, 6, 1)::JSONB,
    'properties', JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'lineProperties', JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'ids', line.ids
        ),
        'coordinateProperties', JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'times', line.times
        )
    )
)
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) AS ids,
         ARRAY_AGG("time") AS times,
         ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT track_id AS id,
           ARRAY_AGG(DATE_PART('EPOCH', logged_at)::INT) AS "time",
           ST_MakeLine(point::GEOMETRY ORDER BY created_at) AS geom   -- created_at or logged_at?
    FROM   coordinates
    WHERE  locatable_id = :id
      AND  user_id = :user_id
    GROUP BY
           track_id
  ) AS lines
) AS line
;
```

---

`ST_AsGeoJSON` comes with a handy signature accepting `RECORD`s (and returning `TEXT`); you'd pass in your `line` rows having nested `JSONB` objects like so

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(line.*, 'geom', 6) -- ::JSONB
FROM (
  SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
           'ids', ARRAY_AGG(id)
         ) AS "lineProperties",
         JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
           'times', ARRAY_AGG("time")
         ) AS "coordinateProperties",
         ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT track_id AS id,
           ARRAY_AGG(logged_at) AS "time",
           ST_MakeLine(point::GEOMETRY ORDER BY created_at) AS geom
    FROM   coordinates
    WHERE  locatable_id = :id
      AND  user_id = :user_id
    GROUP BY
           track_id
  ) AS lines
) AS line
;
```

There will be no `bbox` member, though.

---

And promoting a [set of custom aggregates](https://gist.github.com/geozelot/b2e5cd65dd7f85ec381aeee14e0149ae) I wrote a while back; they return valid `FeatureCollections` (as `JSONB`) like so

```
SELECT ST_AsFeatureCollection(line.*, 'geom', 6)
FROM (
  SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
           'ids', ARRAY_AGG(id)
         ) AS "lineProperties",
         JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
           'times', ARRAY_AGG("time")
         ) AS "coordinateProperties",
         ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT track_id AS id,
           ARRAY_AGG(logged_at) AS "time",
           ST_MakeLine(point::GEOMETRY ORDER BY created_at) AS geom
    FROM   coordinates
    WHERE  locatable_id = :id
      AND  user_id = :user_id
    GROUP BY
           track_id
  ) AS lines
) AS line
;
```

Again, no `bbox` member.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look at your aggregates! As for `created_at` or `logged_at`, we always order by `created_at` cause that column will always be present and gets populated when we import the route from a GeoJson, GPX or FIT file. We assume here that the route will already be sorted properly in the file. GPX and FIT files will have additional data, like a time, associated with a point, where as GeoJson does not (at least not in a structured way).

Comment: Just FYI, you have a type in your first example: `lines.geom` should be `line.geom`. I like that your GeoJSON is much more readable than mine!

Comment: @shabushabu corrected, thx.! Btw. I just thought there may've been a mixup with those names...could've been that one nasty bug that takes two hours to find.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. First, make the line string in the `FROM` query, then collect in the select, so the opposite from what I had... Seems kind of obvious now ;) The `ST_Multi` just makes sure that we have a multi-geometry.

```sql
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'bbox',       ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(lines.line), 6, 1)::jsonb-> 'bbox',
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Multi(ST_Collect(lines.line)), 6)::jsonb,
    'properties', jsonb_build_object(
        'lineProperties',        jsonb_build_object(
            'ids',   array_agg(lines.track_id)
        ),
        'coordinateProperties',  jsonb_build_object(
            'times',   array_agg(lines.time)
        )
    )
)
FROM (
    SELECT
           track_id,
           array_agg(extract(epoch from logged_at)) as time,
           ST_MakeLine(point::geometry ORDER BY created_at) as line
    FROM coordinates
    WHERE locatable_id = :id
    and user_id = :user_id
    GROUP BY track_id
) lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the array variant of [`ST_COLLECT`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) rather than `ST_MULTI`

```
SELECT ST_AsText(  ST_Collect(
    ARRAY[ ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(3 4, 4 5)') ] )) As wktcollect;

--wkt collect --
MULTILINESTRING((1 2,3 4),(3 4,4 5))
```

depending on what exactly is in `lines.line` you might need an `array_agg` on that too to go into the collect.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment about `ST_COLLECT` put me on the right path!